# Let me rephrase I am helping my daughter learn physics. is it possible to determine mass from data that has only distance the object fell and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, acceleration, drag, free-fall

The assignment is already over. I helped her figure out how to determine acceleration, and a rough estimate of air drag, but I was wondering if it is possible to determine mass. I have searched many sites and all of the equations have mass involved. Here is the data from the problem.

The data is from three objects dropped off a tall building.

time (s), object 1 position (m), object 2 position (m), object 3 position (m)

1, 4.9, 2.45, 0.5

2, 19.6, 9.8, 1

3, 44.1, 22.1, 1.5

4, 78.4, 39.2, 2

I have been looking for a formula that I can solve for mass, but I have not been able to. Is that even possible?

Comment: Homework-like and check-my-work like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See [How do I ask homework questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Are check-my-work questions on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more information.

Comment: For passers-by the OP previously posted the same question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326316/i-need-to-estimate-mass-based-on-free-fall-distance-and-time (now automatically deleted as closed  and negatively scored, so 10K only).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it may not be easy.

Without drag, you could not calculate mass. Gravity accelerates objects of all masses at the same rate.

However, drag changes things. A feather falls slower than a rock shaped like the feather.

When dropped, an object falls faster and faster. As the velocity grows, so does the force of drag. When drag is the same as the force of gravity, the object falls at a constant speed. This is called the terminal velocity.

Drag depends on the shape of the object and the speed of the fall. It is not easy to calculate drag, even for a simple sphere. For a complex shape you would likely have to settle for a numeric solution. But it is theoretically possible.

Given your function of speed vs drag and your measured terminal velocity, you can calculate the force of drag. That must equal the force of gravity. Once you know the force of gravity on an object, it is easy to calculate its mass.